# C# System.IO.File.Copy issue

Tags: c#, system.io.file

So I needed to make a quick Windows Form app to process a list of files with their directories and copy them to a new dir. Normally I would use a batch file to do this e.g.

```
@echo off
mkdir "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\inst"

:A
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1 > nul
xcopy "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\M14.0.1512.400-enu-x64.exe" "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\inst" /y
xcopy "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Temp\vcredist.exe" "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\inst" /y

GOTO A
```

I know I'm not using the best practices etc. but its a quick script I came up with to help speed up my work. Now doing this for a couple of files is fine but some of the applications I work on havelike 40+ files that I need to copy over and its a bit of a pain having to write a batch file each time.

So I slapped up a simple WF app with a simple input field and a button to start the process.

The user places a list of files (with the path and dir e.g. C:\foo\bar\hello.txt) into the input field and then the app takes each line from the text box and shoves it into a list after doing some basic filtering e.g. removing \n, \t, \r and encapsulaing the strings with double quotes if they are not in place already.

```
new Thread(() =>
{
Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;

while (run)
{
    foreach (string path in paths)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        try
        {
            File.Copy(path, dir, true);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            g.log.WriteToLog("Failed to copy asset: " + e.ToString());

        }
    }
};

}).Start();
```

When I run that this is what I get in the logs:

```
//LOGS
21/03/2019 11:25:56  -  Failed to copy asset: System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.   at System.IO.LongPathHelper.Normalize(String path, UInt32 maxPathLength, Boolean checkInvalidCharacters, Boolean expandShortPaths)   at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)   at System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path)   at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite, Boolean checkHost)   at S2_PackagingTool.Application_Extractor.ExtractAssets() in C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\GitHub\S2-EnvPrepTool\Application_Extractor.cs:line 98
21/03/2019 11:25:56  -  Path: "C:\Program Files\Freedom Scientific\Runtime JAWS\18.0\jrt.exe" Dir: "C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\GitHub\S2-EnvPrepTool\bin\Debug\Extracted Assets"
```

The second line in the logs is a value dump from the path and dir variables.

When I run the code without the while loop and add the path and dir in manually e.g.

```
File.Copy(@"C:\foo\bar\hello.txt", @"C:\hello\world", true);
```

or

```
File.Copy("C:\\foo\\bar\\hello.txt", "C:\\hello\\world", true);
```

It works fine.

I will also attatch the filter method incase you guys want to see it. Keep in mind this is quick and dirty so yeah:

```
public string QuoteEncapsulationFilter(string s)
{
    s = s.Replace("\n", String.Empty);
    s = s.Replace("\r", String.Empty);
    s = s.Replace("\t", String.Empty);
    s = s.Replace("\\", "\\\\");

    if (!s.Contains("\""))
    {
        s = "\"" + s + "\"";
    }

    return s;
}
```

I have tried looking for an answer everywhere with no luck can someone please shed some light on what I am doing wrong here please. If you need me to provide anymore information please let  me know.

Thanks!

Comment: "encapsulaing the strings with double quotes if they are not in place already" what? Why exactly would you do that? C:\myfile.txt is valid, "C:\myfile.txt" isn't!

Comment: Yeah, that line stuck out to me too.  Needs clarification, because as written it doesn't appear to make sense.

Comment: @Amy Look at the line `s = "\"" + s + "\"";`

Comment: Yeah I know, I saw it.  Doesn't really make sense.

Comment: OP: notice, also, that you cannot provide `%username%` to the `File` API, you need to expand them before

Comment: @Camilio Tarevinto My bad I thought that I would need quotes around the path, and in reponse to your second response about `%username%` that was just in the bat file it worked fine when I used it. The thing is I tried without quotes initially and I was getting an issue hence why I created the encapsulation method.

Comment: @UmaisKhan, the original issue you had before you went down the road of mistakenly slapping double-quotes onto your paths is quite likely the issue mentioned in the answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the file name within the `File.Copy (string sourceFileName, string destFileName, bool overwrite);` function. Your `dir` path needs the file name.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.copy?view=netframework-4.7.2

says the following:

> destFileName
>   String The name of the destination file. This cannot be a
>   directory.

Edit:
To answer your second question in the comments:

```
new Thread(() =>
{
Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;

while (run)
{
    foreach (string path in paths)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        try
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(path); // Get the file name
            var fullDestination = dir + fileName;  // Complete the uri
            File.Copy(path, fullDestination, true);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            g.log.WriteToLog("Failed to copy asset: " + e.ToString());

        }
    }
};

}).Start();
```

Comment: Totally!  Nice catch.  I didn't even see that.  Umais, when you fix it, you should use "System.IO.Path.Combine" and not dir + "\\" + file.

Comment: @Blue Eyed Behemoth - Good spot! This was my issue exactly.  bit silly like but yeah I guess it works. Now I guess I will have to come up with a method to extract the file names and automatically append them to the end of the directory path for each file. Thanks dude!

Comment: @UmaisKhan No problem. You're looking for `File.Copy(path, dir + Path.GetFileName(path), true);` I wouldn't do it in one line for clarity, but `Path.GetFileName(path)` will get you the file name.